# Dynamically creating an array from class c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Throwing this out there first I'm a still learning how to program in school. I'm having an issue reading in to a dynamically created array with a pointer to one of my classes. The function readClassArray() isn't getting the variable back from student.getCreditNumber. The program complies fine in Visual Studio but when I get the the readClassArray it just skips over the function because s.getCreditNumber returns 0.

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Courses{
 private:
  int courseNumber;
  double hours;
  string courseName;
  char grade;
public:
void setCourseNumber(int n){courseNumber = n; }
void setCreditHours(double c) { hours = c; }
void setCourseName(string n) { courseName = n; }
void setGrade(char g) { grade = g; }
int getCourseNumber() { return courseNumber; }
double getCreditHours() { return hours; }
string getCourseName() { return courseName; }
char getGrade() { return grade; }
};
class Student : public Courses{
 private:
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
  string studentNumber;
  int creditNumber;
  double gpa;
 public:
 Courses * courses;
  Student() {
   firstName = " ";
   lastName = " ";
   studentNumber = " ";
   creditNumber = 0;
   gpa = 0.0;
   courses = NULL;
 }
~Student() {
    delete[] courses;
};
void setFirstName(string n) { firstName = n; }
void setLastName(string l) { lastName = l; }
void setStudentNumber(string a) { studentNumber = a; }
void setCreditNumber(int num) { creditNumber = num; }
string getFirstName() { return  firstName; }
string getLastName() { return lastName; }
string getStudentNumber() { return studentNumber; }
int getCreditNumber() { return creditNumber; }
};
#endif
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 using namespace std;

void readStudent();
void readCourseArray();
void computeGPA();
void printSummary();

void readStudent() {
Student a;
string number;
string firstName;
string lastName;
int courses;

cout << "Enter student number: ";
cin >> number;
a.setStudentNumber(number);
cout << "Enter student first name: ";
cin >> firstName;
a.setFirstName(firstName);
cout << "Enter student last name: ";
cin >> lastName;
a.setLastName(lastName);
cout << "Enter student number of courses: ";
cin >> courses;
a.setCreditNumber(courses);

cout << "\n"; }


void readCourseArray(){
Student s;
s.courses = new Courses[s.getCreditNumber()];

int num;
double cHours;
string cName;
char grade;
cout << "test" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < s.getCreditNumber(); i++){
    cout << "Enter class " << i + 1 << " number: ";
    cin >> num;
    s.courses[i].setCourseNumber(num);
    cout << "Enter class " << i + 1 << " name: ";
    cin >> cName;
    s.courses[i].setCourseName(cName);
    cout << "Enter class " << i + 1 << " hours: ";
    cin >> cHours;
    s.courses[i].setCreditHours(cHours);
    cout << "Enter class " << i + 1 << " grade: ";
    cin >> grade;
    s.courses[i].setGrade(grade);
    cout << "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use new[], use std::vector.

Comment: readCourseArray creates a local object s, that is destroyed at the end of the function. That seems to be useless.

Comment: Off topic: Read up on the [Member initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It won't help much here, but it's extremely useful and it doesn't look like anyone 's shown it to you yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of `readCourseArray` you've created `s`. When that happens the value of the `creditNumber` member is 0 as set by the default constructor. You need to do something to set it to a non-zero value. If you're expecting the value set in `readStudent` to carry over you need to plumb the two functions together. Either pass in a `Student` object as a reference to each function, or have `readStudent` return a `Student` object and pass that to `readCourseArray`.